# Why am I getting a No Method Error in my rails app?

Tags: database, ruby-on-rails-3, migration, nomethoderror

I know that I'm a newbie at this and that I am not worthy, but could someone please explain to me why I am getting a No Method Error?  Here's what I did.  I generated a new migration for my database onto my existing rails app, and the migration is called "Profile". I ran db:migrate and then proceeded to edit my previous "new.html.erb" form.  The code looks like this:

```
class CreateProfiles < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    create_table :profiles do |t|
      t.string :major
      t.string :year
      t.string :books_sell
      t.string :books_buy
      t.string :facebook
      t.string :restaurants
      t.string :interests

      t.timestamps
    end
    add_index :profiles, :major
    add_index :profiles, :year
    add_index :profiles, :books_sell
    add_index :profiles, :books_buy
    add_index :profiles, :facebook
    add_index :profiles, :restaurants
    add_index :profiles, :interests
  end

  def self.down
    drop_table :profiles
  end
end
```

Basically, I am adding a profile section onto my app, but I am getting this:

```
   undefined method `major' for #<User:0x00000100b6e030>
    Extracted source (around line #23):

    20:   </div>
    21:   <div class="field">
    22:     <%= f.label :"major" %><br />
    23:     <%= f.text_field :major %>
    24:   </div>
```

This is my views/users/new.hmtl.erb file:

```
<h1>Sign up</h1>

<%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>
  <%= render 'shared/error_messages', :object => f.object %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :name %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :email %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :email %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :password %><br />
    <%= f.password_field :password %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :password_confirmation, "Confirmation" %><br />
    <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation %> 
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :"year" %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :year %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :"major" %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :major %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit "Sign up" %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

What's missing?

Comment: Your form is for a `User` model while your migration was for a `Profile` model. Could this be your problem?

Comment: @Benoit Garret, I think you hit the spot.  I will look into that.

Comment: And seriously, don't apologize for being a newbie. Read this thread about newbie questions: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/97327/can-i-ask-newbie-and-basic-questions-in-stack-overflow.

Comment: @Benoit Garret.  Thanks for the advice and for the link.  I was scolded the other day for posting a "newbie" question.  By the way, I figured it out and will post the answer somewhere! :)

Comment: You could post it here and accept your own answer ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here was that I previously had a form view completed under the user model.  I wanted to tack onto that form and so I created a new migration named profile.  I did this because I was not able to manually rollback my migration of the user model and just tack on strings and columns.

However, adding text fields from the profile model under the user model poses an error.

What I did instead was I created a `Add_xxx_to_yyy` migration which allowed me to add columns onto a previously created migration without any problems.  I used `rails generate migration Add_profile_to_User` with the underscores because I'm on rails 3.0 (it didn't work when I did `Addprofiletouser`). Et voilà!

Comment: You can rollback migrations with `rake db:rollback STEP=n` where `n` is the number of migrations that you want to rollback. I'm always modifying existing migrations when I develop, using rollback + migrate.

Comment: As for the migrations generation, you can either specify your migration name in camel case (`AddProfileToUser`) or in snake case (`add_profile_to_user`).

Answer (score 0):

You've pasted your migration for `Profile` model. And I guess, that in your `@user` variable you have new instance of `User` model.

And since there is no method or attribute `major` defined for your User, you see the complaint "undefined method..."